# Man gets super-intelligence from lightning strike

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie where a guy, struck by thunder while connecting 2 wires of a primitive computer, gains super-calculator abilities. After that, he made a test (maybe at a university) with lightning speed, solving it in a blink of an eye while breaking the silence of the hall by biting and crunching his toast.

If I remember correctly, it was a soft sci-fi movie made by Disney in the 80's, involving a guy in a university and I described that scene. The protagonist entered a computer room during a storm with wet clothes and tries to connect 2 wires of a super computer when a lightning hit the structure and "magically" he acquires supercomputer abilities and knowledge too.

He also enters like a genius, as a member of school team participating in competitions between teams of other universities, winning at least.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is Disney's *The Computer Wore Tennis Shoes*, from 1969, starring a young Kurt Russell:

> While installing a replacement part during a thunderstorm, Riley is zapped and becomes a human computer. He now has superhuman mathematical talent, can read and remember the contents of an encyclopedia volume in a few minutes, and speak a language fluently after reading one textbook. His new abilities make Riley a worldwide celebrity, and Medfield's best chance to win a televised quiz tournament with a $100,000 prize.

Answer (score 6):

As the accepted answer says, this sounds like The Computer Wore Tennis Shoes, which was made twice, once as a Disney theatrical release in 1969 with Kurt Russell, and once as a Disney/ABC TV movie in 1995 with Kirk Cameron in the title role.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065566/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112709/

If the OP clearly remembers it as "at least 80s" they may be remembering the TV version.